# How to restore the state of a table which had been populated with subsequent XHR query

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatables, xmlhttprequest

I have a DataTable table which is populated, in the first place, by a XQuery harvesting the whole set of data in my database. Each record has a hyperlink which takes the user to a 'detail' page. When the user goes back from the detail they should find the table as they left it.

The main page with the table also has an advanced search form, from where the user can filter the results. When submitting the form a JavaScript executes another query, this time via XHR, and repopulates the table.

Now, it all goes well with the full-records table (i.e. when the user doesn't action an advanced search). I have also put a `stateSave: true` option in the initialisation of the table so that when the user comes back from the 'detail' page finds the table as they left it.

The problem starts when an advanced search is carried out. In that case, when going on the 'detail' page and coming back the table is not there any more, so I need to request a new XHR using the parameter I saved in sessionStorage, which is fine. Then, though, I need to put the table as it was. How do I do that? If I add:

```
var table = $('#mainTable').DataTable();

            $('#mainTable').on('page.dt', function () {
                var page = table.page();
                sessionStorage.setItem('pageTable', page);
                table.state.save()
```

And then use that `page` for getting the advanced-search-table to the page the user was consulting with `table.page(parseInt(page)).draw('page')` after the new XHR query triggered by the 'back' button from the 'detail' page the `stateSave: true` on the full-records-table gets ignored. Also, I'd like to save things like sorting of columns and the like. Is there an easy way to save the current state of the advanced-search table when the user clicks on the hyperlink, and restore the table exactly as it was when the user goes back, without executing a new advanced-search query behind the scenes, or executing and then reinitialise the table with all the parameters (page, sorting, scrolling) active at the moment the user left the main page to go to the detail page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I don't feel this has an easy solution. Restoring the full state of the table after a subsequent XHR query seems like a hassle. I've solved by repopulating the table via the server-side XQuery. That way the `stateSave: true` gets honoured, no matter the content of the table.